# Remove <p><strong><br /> &nbsp;</strong></p> with XPATH

Tags: php, regex, xpath, domdocument

I use xpath to remove `<p>&nbsp;</p>`

```
    $nodeList = $xpath->query("//p[text()=\"\xC2\xA0\"]"); # &nbsp;
    foreach($nodeList as $node) 
    {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
```

but it does not remove this,

```
<p><strong><br /> &nbsp;</strong></p>
```

or this kind,

```
<p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
```

How can I remove them?

Or maybe a regex that I should use?

Comment: What of `strip_tags();`?

Comment: `strip_tags();` is either remove all tags or it can't do specific thing like above...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with

```
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//p[normalize-space(.)=\"\xC2\xA0\"]"); # &nbsp;
foreach($nodeList as $node) 
{
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

---

Quoting [**from the docs**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)

> The **`normalize-space`** function returns the argument string with
>   whitespace normalized by stripping leading and trailing whitespace and
>   replacing sequences of whitespace characters by a single space.

Comment: Thanks so much Gaby! It works perfectly! Can I ask - what does `normalize-space(.)` do and mean? Thanks!

Comment: @lauthiamkok, added description and reference to the documentation of `normalize-space`

Comment: Note that non-breaking space character is not a normalizable space so if the text is `&nbsp;&nbsp;` it will not be normalized to one `&nbsp;`

Comment: @jasso, indeed .. it is implied though, since we are testing against `"\xC2\xA0\"` and not against `""` :) .. but good point..