# How to keep <p><img ... /></p> with XPATH?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument, htmltidy

I use XPATH to remove untidy HTML tags,

```
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//*[normalize-space(.)='' and not(self::br)]");
    foreach($nodeList as $node) 
    {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
```

will remove the horrible input like these,

```
<p><em><br /></em></p>
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><em><br /></em></span></p>
```

but it also removes the `img tag` like blow that I want to keep,

```
<p><img title="picture summit" src="images/32913430_127001_e.jpg" alt="picture summit" width="590" height="366" /></p>
```

How can I keep the `img tag` input with XPATH?

Comment: Note that using the element `br` in a paragraph to provoke a carriage return without starting a new paragraph is perfectly valid. You want to remove empty paragraphs ? If so, you will have to explicitly consider the elements you want and those you don't want. Like keep `img` but filter out anything else.

Comment: thanks. yes I want to remove empty paragraphs only...

Comment: Good question, +1. Before even starting to write XPath expressions, it is a good idea to think and specify well exactly what elements inside a `p` make it "non-empty".

Comment: Sibling Question: [Remove <p><strong><br /> &nbsp;</strong></p> with XPATH](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7856414/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//p[not(descendant::*[self::img or self::br]) and normalize-space()='']
```

Comment: Sorry, I got this error actually, `Warning: DOMXPath::query() [domxpath.query]: Invalid expression in C:\wamp\www\test\2011\php\tidy_html\dom_tidy_html_5.php on line 120` it refers to `//p[not(descendant::/*[self::img or self::br]) and normalize-space()='']`...

Comment: I amended the expression and now it works with this `//p[not(descendant::*[self::img or self::br]) and normalize-space()='']`

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Yes, it was a typo, thanks for noticing this -- I already edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an XPath 1.0 expression like the one below to remove unwanted paragraphs:

```
//p[count(text())=0 and count(img)=0]
```