# Keep elements in text with XPath

Tags: java, html, xml, xpath

I have a XML files, and each file contains some informations, it also contains description of itself closed in element `<namespace:description></namespace:description>`. This description will be inserted in HTML web page and uploaded to web.

The problem is that in description element are other HTML elements and I want to keep them there, so that text can be formatted, but XPath escape all those elements and returns only their text.

```
<namespace:descr>Some <i>nice</i> description</namespace:descr>
```

I tried variations on this XPath query: `//*[local-name()='descr']` 
(I'm not really skilled with XPath)

Also tried something like `//*[local-name()='descr']//*[not(descendant::*[self::p or self::i])]` found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860747/how-to-keep-pimg-p-with-xpath), but it doesn't work for me.

So my question: is there some way to keep XML/HTML elements in text after using XPath query?

Comment: Do I understand correctly: `<namespace:descr>Some <i>nice</i> description</namespace:descr>` shall end up as `Some <i>nice</i> description` ?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, exactly.

Comment: Can you add some more example code. How do extract that text and how do you insert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of an XPath expression can either be a string, number, boolean or a node-set. Each of these types can be converted to one of the primitive types.

The expression `//*[local-name()='descr']` returns a node-set but you then obviously convert it to a string which returns the concatenated text content of the first node in the node-set, stripping off all markup.

To print the content of the result node as markup you would need to do the following:

1. Retrieve the expression result as node-set. The implementation type of the node-set depends on the XPath engine, and for instance could be a DOM nodelist.
2. Serialize the nodes as XML fragment. This of course depends on the API node-set and the XPath engine. XSLT could be used for that but it may also be as simple as calling `toString()` on the node implementation.

Comment: Found implementation of your [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300839/get-a-nodes-inner-xml-as-string-in-java-dom).